# Can a professor shout at a student?

Tags: ethics, etiquette, interpersonal-issues, communication

- Is there any possible penalty (from the educational institution) for the professor for disrespecting a student?
- What can and cannot do a professor in terms of respect to a student?

Comment: No, he can not.

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent well he can (it is physically possible), but he *should* not. Nevertheless, a penalty would seem unreasonable for a minor, isolated incident. A professor should treat his or her students just as any normal person would. With respect. Do not talk "down" to them, do not get angry, et cetera.

Comment: By reading your profile information, it seems that you are a high school student at the age of 15. There are two points here. If you are asking a question about teachers and high schools students, this question is off-topic based on the scope defined for this site. Also, answers to your question vastly differs for professors and high school teachers.

Comment: What kind of penalty are you asking about?  Criminal, civil, or imposed by the university?  (In the latter case I imagine it would depend on the university.)

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent yes, that's right but I am not talking about high school teacher, my question is about professors.

Comment: @Moriarty I think that having a *professor* title does not give professors the *right* to shout at students. I have never seen this right in any code of ethics, instructions for teaching or any law. When shouting is unethical and it is not legally accepted in any form, they can not shout at anybody.

Comment: @AlejandroPacheco Regarding the [help center](http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), *You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face*. As far as you are a high school student, you normally have never had any professor as your teacher at high school. So, this question is not your actual problem that you faced before.

Comment: This question is not suitable for this site.  It is subjective, and does not follow our guidelines for subjective questions.  See the [help], especially http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask.  Also, it is unclear what you are asking: are you asking whether professors should yell at a student, or whether they can?  in what context or situation?  If you are asking about what the penalty is, what university and what country?  "What can and cannot a professor do..." is too broad.  So, the question is too broad and unclear.

Comment: Do they have tenure? No --> Minimal, infrequent yelling allowed; Yes --> Almost a non-event unless they touch you.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit and provide a little backup for your assertion?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not asked based on the of scope of this site.

Comment: So true... Also, when they're old full professors "it's just their character"...

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent *You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.* [The purpose of that sentence is not to discourage questions which you are not facing.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/219979/251229) See [this meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/219975/251229) for more info.

Comment: I have nominated the question to be re-opened. The fact that the OP has not faced the problem himself is absolutely irrelevant. @D.W. it seems clear to me that the OP is asking whether a professor can *justifiably* yell at a student. I don't see a huge amount of wiggle room for subjectivity here.

Comment: @Moriarty In the question body, the OP used "disrespect" and "respect". Both words are somewhat subjective. So, to me, the question is unclear. When can you say a professor is disrespecting a student? The question title is also subjective. Some people speak loudly because they have hearing problem. So, how do you define "Shout"?

Comment: I agree with @scaaahu. Despite the fact that the OP hasn't faced the problem, this question seems to be too broad because in each level professors may have different reasons to shout at the students. This may be because of miss-understanding of two people, interpersonal issues, professional issues, etc. Their action changes in front of undergraduate and postgraduate students. Nobody can give precise answer unless he know what really happened to the OP and at what condition the professor shouted at him.

Comment: @Moriarty It's clear that the fact that OP hasn't faced the problem himself is *absolutely* relevant. When the OP's only a high school student, how had he been in a higher education environment? How is he aware of the importances of duties of a postdoc (their roles, their project's budget, etc)? Professors may have reasons to shout at their students (despite the ethical issues). The conditions differ from a high school student who only have seen a teacher (even a TA or undergraduate lecturer) who's reason to shout at students is to calm his class down to be able to teach the content for them.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Under normal circumstances, faculty should never yell or shout at a student. However, faculty are also human beings, and there is always the possibility that under emotional strain, they can lash out at a student.

I will admit to having been guilty of this once as an advisor, when a student came into my office for a discussion about his research, and made some statements that betrayed a total lack of awareness of what he was doing (and this was a "veteran" graduate student who should have known better).

In the context of teaching, students have reason to expect that the faculty member should not shout at them. However, it is unreasonable to expect that any disciplinary action would be taken against a faculty member for a single infraction.

Comment: A safety situation is an exception. And athletic coaches seem to believe they are one.

Comment: On occasion, I will shout at a student to stop writing on his or her exam after the end of the exam period (after having given sufficient warning.) It is the best way to get the attention of someone far away and stop him or her from doing something that he or she should not be doing.  (Perhaps this could be seen as a generalization of @keshlam's safety exception.)

Comment: _it is unreasonable to expect that any disciplinary action would be taken against a faculty member for a single infraction_ That raises the question - can something be done against repeat offenders? I think the answer is _no_ again! (In practice that is, of course the cloud cuckoo land of ethical thinking is different.)

Comment: @TheDarkSide: I mostly agree with your assessment—I think it's highly unlikely a professor would ever be held accountable for such behavior, unless there's a large pattern of such behavior in public, and even then it's not going to amount to much more than a slap on the wrist.

Answer (score 8):

Students and professors owe each other the same level of respect, civility and generally adult behavior, meaning that it is wrong for one to be rude to the other. No particular significance should be attached to a professor shouts at a student who is rudely disrupting a class, since the student has no right to disrupt the class. On the other hand, it would be a significant problem if a professor were to shout at a student for quietly doing poorly on a homework, since the student does, in fact, have the right to do well or do poorly, as they choose. So you can't morally evaluate one person's conduct in a vacuum -- we need to know the full context.

Comment: Agreed. Shouting is not an appropriate response unless the student is being incredibly disrespectful (i.e. disrupting) or there is a concern for safety. However, I would probably call security to have the student removed before I would resort to shouting.

Answer (score 3):

There is no reason for the professor to shout. If a student doesn't behave or has some other problem then the student will suffer (the student can be kicked out of the institution if the student doesn't pass his/her exams). What should happen to a professor who cannot suppress his/her urge to shout? I would say that such a professor should apply for a new job [here](http://www.westpoint.edu/SitePages/Home.aspx), where shouting at under-performing students is compulsory. But they only teach a limited number of subjects there.